# Google sheets If vlookup formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im building a financial dashboard and import table data from stockanalysis.com. I have noticed that i will need to convert reports from CNY to USD eg.Alibaba

Im using vlookup to pull specific data i want into a seperate sheet and a dashboard to summerise that data. The highlighted revenue when converted to USD should be 110812.4498

[image]

this is my attempt at converting but failing.

Any help is appricated

> =if(VLOOKUP(B3,'Income Statement QoQ'!$A$5:$AW$45,3,0)Dashboard!A2 = "CNY",C3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:CNYUSD"))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(Dashboard!A2="CNY", 
 C3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:CNYUSD"), 
 VLOOKUP(B3,'Income Statement QoQ'!$A$5:$AW$45, 3, 0))
```

Comment: REF! error circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see file > spreadsheet settings. Ive changed it but the output is zero

Comment: @Peter can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?